# Undefined variable in callback

Tags: javascript, cordova-plugins

I have a problem with the callback of a Cordova plugin that can be illustrated as the following code:

```
function foo(param) {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        console.log("In:", param);
    }, 1000);

    console.log("Out:", param);
}

foo(1);
```

In this example, I'm pretending the pluging callback call through a simple timeout.

The expected result is:

```
Out: 1
In: 1
```

But the problem I'm facing is that in my real application with real plugin callbacks (not a timeout), sometimes the function parameter value in the callback function is `undefined`, as if in the previous example the result were:

```
Out: 1
In: undefined
```

Does it make sense? Is there any case in which a variable (function parameter) stops being avaliable in a closure?

Comment: Can you share those scenarios ? Make sure you are not accepting argument as argument of callback like `setTimeout(function(param){... `

Comment: It's huge, they are several callbacks called multiple times from different points, some of them from native. Anyways I refactored my code and this issue is not happening any more. Just curious about what could be happening.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any case in which a variable (function parameter) stops being avaliable in a closure?

Yes, if you change your parameter in closure scope by assigning to another value(e.g. `undefined`), see example:

```
function foo(param) {

    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("In:", param);
    }, 1000);

    // some function that returns 'undefined'
    var someFunction = function() {
        return undefined;
    };

    console.log("Out:", param);

    param = someFunction(); // or simply assign to 'undefined'
}

foo(1);
```

Output:

```
Out: 1
In: undefined
```

Comment: You're right, but in my case I can guarantee that the variable has a value when exiting the function scope (`foo` in this example) because I'm printing it with `console.log`